# css not updating on screen- cleared cache, changed browsers, etc

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

I've got kind of an odd problem. Regardless of what I do to the css to style `.blurb`, nothing changes on screen. I've cleared cache in 3 browsers(FF, Chrome, Safari) and yet no changes seem to have been made to the [live site](http://massagebybodyworx.com).

I am trying to have `.blurb` centered within the container, so that regardless of what the text says, there will be equal space on it's right and let side.

Currently, I am using the following:

```
.blurb {
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.blurb p {
    font-family: alexandria;
    font-size: 193%;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

<div class="blurb">
    <p style="text-decoration:underline;color:#f20000;"><span style="color:#282828;">You look like you could use a massage.<br />BodywoRx is here to help.</span></p>
</div><!-- end blurb -->
```

To clear up some confusion, I have 2 related questions.

**1.** I can't see live changes made to CSS regardless of what I've done by way of clearing cache, changing browsers, etc.

**2.** The change I am needing to see is .blurb centered within the container, so that regardless of what the text says, there will be equal space on it's right and let side

Comment: In your original css on the site, the `div.blurb` is already centered (it's width is 700px) (In Chrome try using the developer tools to check) To center text use `text-align: center` like "Hope I Helped"

Comment: @AlvinWong I'm pretty sure the OP wants the text to remain aligned to the left, but to have it centered on the page.

Comment: The text autoflow depends on the width, so it's quite difficult to do that with pure css. Using some JavaScript may help. (P.S. rewrite your question and title as that is not your problem)

Comment: I guess this was sort of a two problem question. 
1. I can't see live changes made to CSS regardless of what I've done by way of clearing cache, changing browsers, etc.
2. The change I am needing to see is .blurb centered within the container, so that regardless of what the text says, there will be equal space on it's right and let side.

Comment: For your first point, have you tried some more obvious changes, like setting `color:red`?

Comment: @AMC - did you look at my answer?

Comment: @Wex, I did and have tried to implement, however I am still struggling with question #1- I can't see live changes made to CSS regardless of what I've done by way of clearing cache, changing browsers, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<p>` is a block-level element. As such, it will take up the entire width of the container, unless its width is fixed. You can center inline elements, such as `<span>` tags, by making the parent have `text-align: center`. To make the `<span>` have `text-align: left`, use `display: inline-block`.

```
<p class="blurb">
    <span>
        You look like you could use a massage.<br />BodywoRx is here to help.
    </span>
</p>
```

CSS:

```
.blurb { text-align: center; }
.blurb > span { text-align: left; display: inline-block; }
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/h2njQ/

Comment: good hack, the only thing to note is IE6 (if the OP cares) :P

Comment: although using inline styles or more complex selectors seems to be better in this case, like `.blurb>span`

Comment: Sure, I was just trying to illustrate a point though. I've updated my answer to reflect those selectors.

Comment: Have you opened your CSS file directly and tried reloading it there? Are you using some kind of CMS where you could clear its cache?

Comment: Ah, that was it.. For some reason, updating the files via FTP which usually works wasn't working in this case. Went directly into WP and made the changes you recommended. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To center your text, you will need to use `text-align`:

```
.blurb {
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

If you simply wish to center the content, you will need to make sure its parent container has a fixed width OR that `blurb` has a fixed width. Right now, it's taking up 100% of its parent container (which may be the webpage), causing `margin:auto` to be ineffective on the horizontal angle.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: I've tried adjusting the width of .blurb, but again, regardless of what I do, the width isn't changed and therefore the centering doesn't take effect.